# android FM receiver -chipset info

Tags: android

I want to develop a custom FM radio app for the android phones, which have FM receiver chip in it.

Through research I've found out that FM receievers are commonly developed by BroadComm.

1. Do the major android phone manufacturers--Samsung, HTC, Sony Ericson use the FM receivers of BroadCom?
2. BCM 2075 supports FM functionality too, was wondering which handsets of samsung/htc/sony have this chip?
3. Where can I get the information of various FM chips used by different phone manufacturers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not actually a specific answer but it can gives you some hint (I hope).

You should probably check out the [Spirit FM](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mikersmicros.fm_unlock) app. On XDA there's the author that is probably the best expert on this. Custom roms don't have FM radio app because of the proprietary drivers, it's actually very complex to build one.

The link of the thread where to investigate further: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1059296